# my cars coolant dries up atleast less than a half litre after i drive around 400 km. why?

Tags: coolant

In my car, coolant dries up fast and after i drive around 400 kms, again I have to feel up at least less than a half litre. Why it is? No leakage.

Comment: Is your exhaust smoke unusually thick and/or white? Is the oil under the filler cap not white and creamy?

Comment: Oh, it's leaking somewhere...  It might be an internal engine leak like @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing is talking about but if you have to ever put more coolant in, it leaked out somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

**You could have a head gasket leak into your cylinders**

If you do have that issue you would not see any coolant leaking from the motor.  It would be going into your combustion chamber where the air and fuel are ignited thereby driving your piston down.

You would troubleshoot this with a leakdown tester or a compression tester.

Leakdown Tester Instructions

[What is a leak down tester and what can I do with it?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/26384/what-is-a-leak-down-tester-and-what-can-i-do-with-it)

This is a similar post that illustrates blown head gasket troubleshooting.  The difference in your case, if you have a blown head gasket would be that you are leaking coolant into your combustion chamber instead of into your oil.

[How do I troubleshoot the source of oil in my coolant?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/26363/how-do-i-troubleshoot-the-source-of-oil-in-my-coolant/26552#26552)

Here is an article on [howto perform a compression test.](http://www.popularmechanics.com/cars/how-to/a8520/cars-101-how-to-do-a-compression-test-14912158/)

If you have no coolant leak and you are losing coolant there is a good chance that it's leaking into your combustion chamber.

Hope this helps, cheers!